# How do I control the car object model using live data?

Tags: three.js

I am working on a car dashboard. I want to dynamically update the car movement using live data stored in a mysql db using car object model.

I do have tried using `three.js` but was unable to pass the parameters dynamically.

Is there any way I can do this?

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - baked illumination</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background:#000;
                color:#000;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                font-family:monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
            }

            a { color:skyblue }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                color: #fff;
                background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                z-index:100;
                display:block;
            }

            #stats { position: absolute; top:5px; left: 0; z-index: 100 }
            #stats #fps { background: transparent !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsText { color: #aaa !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsGraph { display: none }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> webgl - baked + real-time illumination -
        using <a href="http://code.google.com/p/js-openctm/">js-openctm</a> -
        camaro by <a href="http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/blender-camaro/411348" target="_blank">dskfnwn</a> -
        skybox by <a href="http://ict.debevec.org/~debevec/" target="_blank">Paul Debevec</a>
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/ctm/lzma.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/ctm/ctm.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            var FLOOR = -250;

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, controls;
            var renderer;

            var mesh;

            var textureCube;
            var cameraCube, sceneCube;

            var loader;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                // CAMERA

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 25, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.set( 185, 40, 170 );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
                controls.minDistance = 200;
                controls.maxDistance = 500;

                // SCENE

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // SKYBOX

                sceneCube = new THREE.Scene();
                cameraCube = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 25, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                sceneCube.add( cameraCube );

                var r = "textures/cube/pisa/";
                var urls = [ r + "px.png", r + "nx.png",
                             r + "py.png", r + "ny.png",
                             r + "pz.png", r + "nz.png" ];


                textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );

                var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
                shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

                var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
                    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
                    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
                    depthWrite: false,
                    side: THREE.BackSide

                } ),

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 ), material );
                sceneCube.add( mesh );

                // LIGHTS

                var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
                light.position.set( 2, 5, 1 );
                light.position.multiplyScalar( 30 );
                scene.add( light );

                var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 );
                light.position.set( -12, 4.6, 2.4 );
                light.position.multiplyScalar( 30 );
                scene.add( light );

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x050505 ) );

                // RENDERER

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";

                renderer.autoClear = false;

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                // STATS

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                // EVENTS

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                // LOADER

                var start = Date.now();

                // new way via CTMLoader and separate parts

                loaderCTM = new THREE.CTMLoader();

                var position = new THREE.Vector3( -105, -78, -40 );
                var scale = new THREE.Vector3( 30, 30, 30 );

                loaderCTM.loadParts( "models/ctm/camaro/camaro.js", function( geometries, materials ) {

                    hackMaterials( materials );

                    for ( var i = 0; i < geometries.length; i ++ ) {

                        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometries[ i ], materials[ i ] );
                        mesh.position.copy( position );
                        mesh.scale.copy( scale );
                        scene.add( mesh );

                    }

                    var end = Date.now();

                    console.log( "load time:", end - start, "ms" );

                }, { useWorker: true } );

            }

            //

            function hackMaterials( materials ) {

                for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {

                    var m = materials[ i ];

                    if ( m.name.indexOf( "Body" ) !== -1 ) {

                        var mm = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: m.map } );

                        mm.envMap = textureCube;
                        mm.combine = THREE.MixOperation;
                        mm.reflectivity = 0.75;

                        materials[ i ] = mm;

                    } else if ( m.name.indexOf( "mirror" ) !== -1 ) {

                        var mm = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: m.map } );

                        mm.envMap = textureCube;
                        mm.combine = THREE.MultiplyOperation;

                        materials[ i ] = mm;

                    } else if ( m.name.indexOf( "glass" ) !== -1 ) {

                        var mm = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: m.map } );

                        mm.envMap = textureCube;
                        mm.color.copy( m.color );
                        mm.combine = THREE.MixOperation;
                        mm.reflectivity = 0.25;
                        mm.opacity = m.opacity;
                        mm.transparent = true;

                        materials[ i ] = mm;

                    } else if ( m.name.indexOf( "Material.001" ) !== -1 ) {

                        var mm = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: m.map } );

                        mm.shininess = 30;
                        mm.color.setHex( 0x404040 );
                        mm.metal = true;

                        materials[ i ] = mm;

                    }

                    materials[ i ].side = THREE.DoubleSide;

                }

            }

            //

            function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, s ) {

                geometry.center();

                hackMaterials( materials );

                var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
                mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
                scene.add( mesh );

            }

            //

            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
                SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

                camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                cameraCube.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
                cameraCube.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }


            function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                controls.update();

                cameraCube.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );

                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( sceneCube, cameraCube );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please supply the code you've tried using three.js.

Comment: Yes without any code we cannot start to assume how you have tried to do this. A minimal JS fiddle would be best.

Comment: Your question (and code) is missing some important bits. Your three.js code is running on the *client*, your MySQL database is on a *server* somewhere... *how are the two supposed to communicate*? A common solution is to write a simple interface in php, and have the client javascript do periodic ajax calls (using, for example, jQuery) for the updated data. You either have implemented something similar (in which case you should mention details on what went wrong) or still need to design that bit (which is too broad a question, and not three.js related).

Comment: i am unable to make it dynamic ,which values to change either camera position or the obj angles?